# Inset Boundary not working in Blender 3.2

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

i have tried multiple times but the inset boundary feature isn't working in blender 3.2 . is it only me or anyone else facing the problem also?

Comment: it works fine for me, could you please show a animated gif or something? Maybe you have an inner face?

Answer (score -3):

I had the same issue, and I solve when discovery that we need press ctrl+b then when the lines appear no more  press them and press the left bottom and select the area.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please try again to formulate an answer that expresses in English what you mean. The way the question is currently worded, it is difficult for me to correct it, because unfortunately I really don't understand what you are proposing as a solution here. Try https://www.deepl.com/. Thank you for your understanding!